Custom Course Field to be visible in Moodle Course Overview ( ../my/courses.php)
since i'm new in Moodle . i'm having a difficulty on Custom Course Field to be visible in Moodle Course Overview ( ../my/courses.php) Since it is written in Mustache .
view on course card
the left image shown is in php , while the right image shown is using mustache . as you can see the custom course fields are not visible on the right image. i want the custom course field to be able to visible so the course card would be the same as the left image.
Thanks
